# Adjusting the radii of two circles, with known distance between circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, average

If I know `radius1`, and `radius2`, and the distance between them `d`, is there a formula that can adjust the radii so that the circles become intersecting if they are not already?

Points are ruled out through these rules:

```
d > radius1 + radius2
d < |radius1 - radius2|
d = 0
radius1 = radius2
```

If any of the above rules are met, the circles do not intersect. I need a way to adjust the radii for each case - to make the circles intersect (I am estimating a location)

Comment: There are many ways to make this adjustment, e.g., simply split the difference. You need to decide what other properties you want this adjustment to have, such as preserving the relative radii or areas of the two circles.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who knows swift, this explains what I did - its simple addition/subtraction:

```
if r1 > r2 {
    r1Adjusted = Float(distanceBetween) + r2 - 0.1
}
else if r2 > r1){
    r2Adjusted = Float(distanceBetween) + r1Bigger - 0.1
}
```

It is quite simple I know, feel free to elaborate.